# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException:

Tags: hibernate

Hello Viewers this is a ManyToOne RelationShip Programme of hibernate it has total 4 files (Customers,Vendor model class,Test is client class and last one is hibernate configuration Class)

both files one is Customers and another one is Vendor both having a fields and respected tables also mentioned kindly have a look and reply solutions but the exception showing exception details attached[![Exception Details][1]][1]

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com/test/model/Customers] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at com.test.client.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/test/model/Customers
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2366)
    ... 5 more

    Customers.java



package com.test.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers100")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "custid")
    private int customerId;

    @Column(name = "custName", length=10)
    private String customerName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="venid",referencedColumnName="vid")
    private Vendor parent;

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public Vendor getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Vendor parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}



    Vendor.java


package com.test.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Vendor100")

public class Vendor{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "vid")
    private int vendorId;

    @Column(name = "vname", length=10)
    private String vendorName;

    public int getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
    }

    public void setVendorId(int vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

}



hibernate.cfg.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
                <property name="connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="connection.password">root</property>

                <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

                <mapping class="com/test/model/Customers"></mapping>
                <mapping class="com/test/model/Vendor"></mapping>
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>



Test.java

package com.test.client;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.test.model.Customers;
import com.test.model.Vendor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("com/test/cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml"); 

        SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();        

        Vendor v =new Vendor();

        v.setVendorId(100);
        v.setVendorName("java4s6");

        Customers c1=new Customers();

        c1.setCustomerId(504);
        c1.setCustomerName("customer4");
        c1.setParent(v);

        Customers c2=new Customers();

        c2.setCustomerId(505);
        c2.setCustomerName("customer5");
        c2.setParent(v);

        Customers c3=new Customers();

        c3.setCustomerId(506);
        c3.setCustomerName("customer6");
        c3.setParent(v);                             

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        //session.save(v);
        session.save(c2);
        session.save(c2);
        session.save(c3);

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("Many to One with annotation done...!!");
        factory.close();
    }   
}
```

complete error details again printed have a look once

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com/test/model/Customers] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2290)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2243)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at com.test.client.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/test/model/Customers
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2366)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Try update your configuration class mapping `<mapping class="com.test.model.Customers"></mapping>`

Comment: Tijkijiki, superb and thank u sir it is working how small mistake i had committed